# Tried everything to get WIFI working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-drivers

I installed dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.
Wifi was working alright and suddenly I have "No WIfi adapter found"
I've tried many things, basically what is referred here:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/0a751e30e3aed5e6e0f72123031012abda91ca1a

But I don't find a solution.

```
lshw -C network 
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7700000-f7703fff
```

I'm not sure if it's related to the Wifi Product (Wireless-AC 9260) or something else entirely.

```
➜  ~ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 26)
➜  ~ uname -r
5.3.0-59-generic
```

Comment: Shutdown Windows properly. This is the fast start problem. But after you "tried everything" it may be more problematic.

Comment: Well.. you were absolutely right, unabled fast-boot it and it worked immediately. So much time lost.   
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Fast Boot in Windows.

Windows doesn't shut down with Fast Boot enabled but hibernates.

That leads to problems with hardware on Ubuntu.